# Xamarin Firebase iOS 11 No FCM Token Generated

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My app registers with firebase for push notifications, receives a token, and then provides that token as a querystring parameter of the url loaded by a webview.

Although the code executes and no failures are reported, the token is always null in iOS 11.

**The below code works on iOS v9.x on either remote simulator or installed on a device, but does not work in either environment when iOS v11.x.**

Has anyone experienced this? Anyone have helpful suggestions? Thank you in advance for your assistance, I'm pulling out what's left of my hair over here.

I am using the following packages/versions:

- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging v2.0.4.1
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core v4.0.13
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceId v2.0.8

From AppDelegate.cs:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

        // Register your app for remote notifications.
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10 or later
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(granted);
            });

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

        //configure firebase analytics.
        App.Configure();

        DoFCMConnect();
        return true;
    }

    private void DoFCMConnect()
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Connected to FCM");

        //removed when updated to newest firebase version
        //Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect(error => {
        //    if (error != null)
        //    {
        //        System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Re-Connection to FCM Failed: {0}", error.ToString()));
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        System.Console.WriteLine("Re-Connected to FCM.");
        //    }
        //});
    }
```

From WebViewController.cs:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        string url = "https://www.mydomainname.com"; // NOTE: https secure request is required.

        string token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
        string fcm = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken;

        if (token == null && fcm != null)
        {
            token = fcm;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            url += "/login";
        }
        else
        {
            url += "/app-in/{0}"; //page accepts token and associates it to the user after login.
            url = String.Format(url, System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));
        }

        WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));

    }
```

Both string token and string fcm contain a value for iOS 9, however both are null in iOS 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue , refer to [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/327).

Try the steps provided by rsattar.

- downgrade `FirebaseInstanceID` to 2.0.0
- place `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` at first line in `FinishedLaunching`.
- uninstall/reinstall your app.

Comment: Thank you for your response - this did assist greatly.  I had previously attempted to downgrade as other posts recommended, but what I failed to do was: remove all of the Firebase.iOS packages via NuGet and then re-install .CloudMessaging 2.0 with lowest dependency.  Hope that tidbit helps others.  Thank you again for your response, Cole.